I used Cache in Laravel to ban spaming IPs, searching for a better solution
This is how I do it:
$ip = $request->ip();

if (Cache::has('banned_ip_' . $ip)) {
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Access blocked',
        'reason' => 'You have been banned from accessing this service.'
    ], Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
}
if (
    str_contains($code, 'admin') ||
    str_contains($code, 'env') ||
    str_contains($code, 'config') ||
    str_contains($code, 'php') ||
    str_contains($code, 'service') ||
    str_contains($code, 'setting') ||
    str_contains($code, 'server')
) {
    Log::channel('shortLink')->warning('Blocked access for code: ' . $code . ' from IP: ' . $ip);

    Cache::put('banned_ip_' . $ip, true, now()->addDay());

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Access blocked',
        'reason' => 'Forbidden code detected, your IP has been banned.'
    ], Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
}

I'm looking for a better way to do this but I have no idea what to do.
And this code is in the middleware.
I expect a better way if theres one.

it's not clear what your second part of the code is trying to do, since it looks like it's not banning based on some spamming countrt/condition

You can use this package to block ips https://laravel-news.com/laravel-abuse-ip

So if you refresh the cache the banned IPs would be gone? Also, define spam, if it is spam on a form, implement something there instead of keeping track of a list of IPs.

A better way in terms of what? Rewriting the existing code with the exact same functionality? Replacing any part of the current implementation with something els?

You can use this package Laravel Firewall instead of creating one from scratch. It supports more features, including:
Example Usage
Middlewares are already defined, so you just need to add them to your routes. The firewall.all middleware applies all the middlewares available in the all_middleware array of the config file:
Route::group(['middleware' => 'firewall.all'], function () {
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
});

You can also apply each middleware per route. For example, to allow only whitelisted IPs to access the admin area:
Route::group(['middleware' => 'firewall.whitelist'], function () {
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');
});

